# multiple ifs in one row of cmd

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

Does anybody know a way of having multiple if-cases in one line of cmd code?

I mean not nested if cases, but a row.

I need *cmd* to still execute a second *if* case which is in the same line, even if the first one returns *false*.

See this simple example:

```
IF NOT EXIST test\ (mkdir test) & IF NOT EXIST test\folder\ (mkdir test\folder)
```

This will always skip the second *IF*, if the first one is *false*, but I need it to never skip, wether it's *true* or not.

Comment: Why does it need to be a one-liner?

Comment: i have an excel which generates the code because it's a lot of different cases

Comment: I can reproduce it.

Comment: You don't need to check if the directory exists before trying to create it.  If you try to create it and it already exists, the command will just output an error which you can suppress.  You also do not need to make each individual directory.  You can create them all at once with one make directory command. `mkdir "test\folder" 2>nul`.

Comment: it's possible to write a newline in both a formula and VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why it isn't working, because `command1&command2` runs command2 regardless of the status of command1. That said, I confirm it isn't working for you. To get around this, put both commands in parentheses.

`(IF NOT EXIST test\ (mkdir test)) & (IF NOT EXIST test\folder\ (mkdir test\folder))`

Comment: Might it be that the code in the question is regarded as `IF NOT EXIST test\ ((mkdir test) & (IF NOT EXIST test\folder\ (mkdir test\folder)))`?

Comment: @double-beep - Why? The question isn't off topic. There's a behavior that is occurring even though it shouldn't be, and there is a solution that can be provided. An MCVE was posted and the problem was reproduced. It's a valid question.

Comment: @double-beep - I already said that I _can_ reproduce it. Check to make sure you didn't mess something up on your side.

Comment: That is the expected behavior of `IF` but many don't know it or simply forget about it because this behavior seems odd to them. BTW `if condition command_1 & command_2 & ... & command_n` is equivalent to `if condition (command_1 & command_2 & ... & command_n)` that is the whole line belongs to `IF`. So for example to make `command_2` independent of `IF` you have to limit the territory of `IF` by surrounding the whole `IF` construct between the parenthesis: `(if condition command_1) & command_2` The same applies to `for ... do ...` the whole line belongs to `FOR` unless: `(for ... do ....)`